# Leaving out <constructor-arg/> in spring framework when there's a default parameter value

Tags: c#, spring.net

I have the following simple constructor:

```
public SimpleClass(Type1 arg1, int interval = 1000)
{ ... }
```

I'm initialising this using the spring framework as follows, without using `autowire`:

```
<object name="SimpleClass" type="..., ...">     
    <constructor-arg name="arg1" ref="..." />
    <constructor-arg name="interval" value="1000" />    
</object>
```

My question is: Since I'm defining a default value for the second parameter in the actual constructor, can I leave it out of the spring config file, or does spring need an explicit declaration for all parameters if you don't use `autowire`? Is there any point in leaving in a default parameter value here, since I'm using spring?

Comment: what's the 'object' tag? is the question referring to spring.net?

Comment: @abalogh, yes, I'm talking about spring.net, I assumed the `spring` tag was the right one. Is it not?

Comment: @Bozho, I haven't tried leaving it out as it's a big project that takes forever to build and I was hoping to get a quick answer here from someone who knows for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work when using xml configuration (tested it with Spring.NET 1.3.1).

It probably does work when using [CodeConfig](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/), but I haven't tried it out.

Quickest work-around would be to simply introduce a second constructor in your class:

```
Class SimpleClass
{
  public SimpleClass(Type1 arg1) : this(arg1, 1000)
  {}

  public SimpleClass(Type1 arg1, int interval = 1000)
  { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

That will always work.